# Triple integral from complex logarithem

Tags: calculus, integration

How can we solve this problem?
$$\Omega =\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\ln \left(x+e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}y+e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}z\right)dxdydz$$
As my solution, I got the below result:
$$\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\ln \left(x+e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}y+e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}z\right)dxdydz=\frac{\pi i}{6}-\frac{11}{6}$$
But my result did not match wolframe alpha, Is there anyone can verify my result is wrong or wolframe alpha's result?

Comment: The value of the triple integral should be equal to its complex conjugate. This can be seen at a glance by swapping the roles of $y$ and $z$ in the integral. So I don’t think the value you found can be correct.